# Directory.SetAccessControl set unnecessary permissions

Tags: c#, directory, file-permissions, acl

I am trying to set program's installation folder permissions restricted only to Administrators.

There are two scenarios: the folder needs creation and folder already exists.

Here is my code:

```
    public static void CreatePrivateFolder(string path)
    {
        SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);
        DirectorySecurity securityRules = new DirectorySecurity();
        FileSystemAccessRule fsRule =
            new FileSystemAccessRule(sid, FileSystemRights.FullControl,
            InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
            PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow);

        securityRules.SetAccessRule(fsRule);

        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.SetAccessControl(path, securityRules);
        }
        else
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path, securityRules);
        }                
    }
```

When the folder needs creation, the `CreateDirectory` works fine, the folder's permissions restricted only to Administrators.

The strange thing is when I am re-run this code and flow to `SetAccessControl` - the folder's permissions being reset to regular folder with no restricted access.

What do I'm doing wrong?

Folder security results (for path `c:\\folderCheck`) :
[image]

**Update**
anrei [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33743221/2069294) answering my question.
However, it seem to be the same problem in a different way:
If the folder already exists with unrestricted permissions, anrei's code don't seem to be work.
The folder's permissions remain unrestricted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead of your `if (Directory.Exists(path))` block.

```
// what is
var existingACL = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
// remove everything from what is
foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in existingACL.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)))
        existingACL.RemoveAccessRuleAll(rule);
// add yours to what is           
existingACL.AddAccessRule (fsRule);
// set again
Directory.SetAccessControl(path, existingACL);
```

Comment: @anrei, thanks for you answer. Your solution works when the folder already exists with restrict permissions. However, when the folder exists without restrict permissions the code doesn't overwrite those rules and the folder remain accessible.